# Node.js login auth system doesn't store user properly

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, session, passport.js

Assuming I have required `passport`, `bcrypt`, `express-sessions` and `mysql` correctly this code is supposed to add the user info to the session. I cannot for the life of me work out where it is going wrong.
`App.js` file

```
passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true //passback entire req to call back
}, function(req, email, password, done) {

    connection.query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = ?", [email], async(err, rows, fields) => {
        //if an error occurrs in mysql
        if (err) {
            return done(null, false)
            connection.end()
        }
        //if there are no matching entries
        if (!rows.length) {
            console.log('invalid email')
            return done(null, false)
            connection.end()
        }
        //if the passwords don't compare
        if (!(await bcrypt.compare(password, rows[0].password))) {
            console.log('incorrect password')
            done(null, false)
            connection.end()
        }
        //if none of that happens
        req.session.user = rows[0]
        console.log('logged in')
        connection.end()
    });
}));

//handles de/serialization of the user data (all integrated from passport docs)
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    return done(null, user.id)
    console.log(user.id + "serialized")
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id = " + id, function(err, rows) {
       console.log('done' + rows[0])
       return done(err, rows[0])
    });
});
```

Auth route code

```
router.post('/auth', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/account'
}));
```

The code logs the user in, which is logged in the `console`, then logs them out again with a failure redirect to `/account`. I don't know where the authentication is going wrong, thanks for any replies in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same using express-session..

1. install express-session: `npm i express-session --save`
2. Require it in your node application: `var session = require('express-session');`
3. Configure: `app.use(session({ secret: "YourSecretKeyGoesHere", saveUninitialized: true, resave: true }));`

And then check your session..